# Proving a map onto

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, harmonic-analysis

Define a map on the unit disc  $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| \text{ <1 }\}$

$$w(z)=f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$$
**Question** Prove that $w(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ maps the unit disc $D$ **onto** the plane $\Re(w)>1/2.$

**Attempt**
$$w=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$$
then,
$$z^2=\frac{1-w}{w}$$
$|z|<1$ is mapped to $\Re(w)>1/2$

Define, $S=\{w\in \mathbb{C} \mid \Re(w) \text{ >1/2 }\}$

$f:\mathbb{D}\to S$

Let, $w_0\in S$ then $\Re(w_0)>1/2$
then there exists

$z_0=\sqrt{\frac{1-w_0}{w_0}}\in \mathbb{D}$ such that $$f(z_0)=w_0$$

Comment: Question - At $z_0=0$ the function $w$ is multivalued. How to find preimage of $w_0=1$?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't see that $z\to -z^2$ maps the unit disk to itself. And you already investigated $s\to 1/(1-s)$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks. So the map is onto? What happens when $z=0$?

Comment: In function $f(z)=-z^2$ , $z=0$ is a branch point. Is it onto from unit disc to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is plain from the first equation  $w \neq 0$.  You already have obtained,
$$
z^2 = \frac{1-w}{w}
$$
and $|z^2| < 1$ if and only if $|z|<1$, thus $|z|<1$ if and only if,
$$
\left\lvert \frac{1-w}{w} \right\rvert < 1.
$$
That is true if and only if we also have,
$$
\left\lvert \frac{1-\overline w}{\overline w} \right\rvert < 1.
$$
Taking the product, the last  equation is true if and only if,
$$
\left\lvert \frac{1-w}{w} \right\rvert^2 = \frac{1-w}{w} \cdot  \frac{1-\overline w}{\overline w} < 1,
$$
which holds if and only if,
$$
1 - 2 \Re w +|w|^2 < |w|^2
$$
so that $\Re w > \tfrac{1}{2}$.  This shows $w \in S$ as required.  But each step step in the above argument is reversible so that if $w \in S$ then $|z| < 1$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123632/discussion-on-answer-by-wa-don-w-frac11z2-maps-the-unit-disc-onto-the-p).